# Apache tika - how to extract comments from the xls files

Tags: python, excel, comments, xls, apache-tika

I want to extract the comments from xls file in python. I am using Python-tika for the same. When i use tika to get the text I am getting comments as a part of response in between sheets but I want to have them separately. I tried to parse the content but could not figure out where one comments and other starts, also when comments end and new sheet starts.
Here is sample response I am getting with tika:

```
Estimates Geography File with Census and FIPS Codes

fipscensus
        Table with column headers in row 7.  Area name in column J.
        Estimates Geography File with Census and FIPS Codes
        Source:  U.S. Census Bureau
        Internet Release date:  January 20, 2004
        State Code (FIPS)       County Code (FIPS)      County Subdivision Code (Census)        Place Code (Census)     Consolidated City Code (Census) County Subdivision Code (FIPS)       Place Code (FIPS)       Consolidated City Code (FIPS)   Summary Level   Area Name (including legal/statistical area description)
        01      000     000     0000    0000    00000   00000   00000   040     Alabama
        01      000     000     0005    0000    00000   00124   00000   162     Abbeville city
        01      000     000     0010    0000    00000   00460   00000   162     12Page &P
        01      000     000     0015    0000    00000   00484   00000   162     Addison town
        01      000     000     0020    0000    00000   00676   00000   162     Akron town
        01      000     000     0025    0000    00000   00820   00000   162     Alabaster city
        01      000     000     0030    0000    00000   00988   00000   162     Albertville city
        01      000     000     0035    0000    00000   01132   00000   162     Alexander City city
        01      000     000     0040    0000    00000   01228   00000   162     Aliceville city
        01      000     000     0045    0000    00000   01396   00000   162     Allgood town
        01      000     000     0050    0000    00000   01660   00000   162     Altoona town
        01      000     000     0055    0000    00000   01708   00000   162     Andalusia city
        01      000     000     0057    0000    00000   01756   00000   162     Anderson town
        01      000     000     0060    0000    00000   01852   00000   162     Anniston city
        01      000     000     0065    0000    00000   02116   00000   162     Arab city
        01      000     000     0070    0000    00000   02260   00000   162     Ardmore town
        01      000     000     0073    0000    00000   02320   00000   162     Argo town
        01      000     000     0075    0000    00000   02428   00000   162     Ariton town
        01      000     000     0077    0000    00000   02500   00000   162     Arley town
        01      000     000     0080    0000    00000   02836   00000   162     Ashford city
        01      000     000     0085    0000    00000   02860   00000   162     Ashland city
        01      000     000     0090    0000    00000   02908   00000   162     Ashville town
        01      000     000     0095    0000    00000   02956   00000   162     12Page &P
        01      000     000     0100    0000    00000   03004   00000   162     Atmore city
        01      000     000     0105    0000    00000   03028   00000   162     Attalla city
        01      000     000     0110    0000    00000   03076   00000   162     Auburn city
        01      000     000     0115    0000    00000   03220   00000   162     Autaugaville town
        01      000     000     0120    0000    00000   03364   00000   162     Avon town
        01      000     000     0125    0000    00000   03556   00000   162     Babbie town
        01      000     000     0127    0000    00000   03676   00000   162     Baileyton town
        01      000     000     0128    0000    00000   03724   00000   162     Bakerhill city
        01      000     000     0130    0000    00000   03940   00000   162     Banks town

&CPage &P of &N
Mugdha test comment 
Meenal:
Test Comment to check xls parser
Mugdha comment with new line

New line comment

Sheet2
```

Here there are 3 different comments and name of next sheet is "Sheet2":

1. Mugdha comment with new line

New line comment

2. Mugdha test comment
3. Meenal:
   Test Comment to check xls parser

I also tried using java tika but could not get the comments separately.

Comment: Ask Apache Tika for the XHTML version instead of the Plain Text version, then split out the comments before down-sampling the numbers out?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. It worked perfectly for me. I just needed to apply the html parser on top it.